# Why is my text not right aligned properly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why is my test not right-aligned properly like my text in the left.

```
<div class="project-container">               
<h4 class="progress-label">Java</h4>    
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"
       style="width: 60%;">         
    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/gnfbvxtb

Comment: the link is not the same as the code you are showing here in the question !?

Answer (score 0):

My answer based on the link you provided. The main problem is the height you are setting at various places in your css code.

```
.progress-title{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.progress-title-right{
  float: right;
}

.project-container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
}


.progress-stacked {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Do check your other classes for any issue with pseudo classes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your closing `div` is misplaced.  In other words, your `<span class="progress-title-right">Some title</span>` should be immediately before the `<div class="progress">`.

Here's the fiddle with updated HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/8kekB/.